# ng-repeat not showing anything when ng-model is above it in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been teaching myself angular and am currently following this tutorial, https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial, except I haven't cloned the repo down and am using different data to keep it interesting.

My issue is probably a very simple mistake I am making but I'm still trying to understand the concepts/jargon of the framework which makes it hard to search for an answer.

When my template looks like this ..

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="electorate in $ctrl.electorates | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp">
     <p>{{electorate.electorate}}</p>
     <p>{{electorate.mp}} </p>
     <p>{{electorate.party}} </p>
   </li>
 </ul>

 <div> Search: <input ng-model="$ctrl.query"/>
   <p>
     Sort by:
     <select ng-model="$ctrl.orderProp">
       <option value="party">Party</option>
       <option value="mp">MP - Alphabetical</option>
     </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

.. I can type in the search input box to filter the ng-repeat list and order them by the sort by options just fine.

But it would look better with the search/sort by options above the data like so..

```
<div>
 <div> Search: <input ng-model="$ctrl.query"/>
 <p>
   Sort by:
   <select ng-model="$ctrl.orderProp">
     <option value="party">Party</option>
     <option value="mp">MP - Alphabetical</option>
   </p>
 </div>
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="electorate in $ctrl.electorates | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp">
     <p>{{electorate.electorate}}</p>
     <p>{{electorate.mp}} </p>
     <p>{{electorate.party}} </p>
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

.. except while it shows the search/sort by options, the ng-repeat data never appears.

Why is this and how do I make it work in the way I want?

I don't see any big differences between what I have done and the tutorial (specifically around steps 3 - 7) and my guess was it is due to the search/sort referencing the data before it is ready, however in the tutorial it is structured this way no problem.

Here is my controller as well

```
angular.
  module('electorateList').
  component('electorateList', {
    templateUrl: 'electorate-list/electorate-list.template.html',
    controller: function ElectorateListController($http){
          var self = this;
          self.orderProp = 'party';


          $http.get('electorates.json').then(function(response){
            self.electorates = response.data;
          });
        }
  });
```

Thanks and feel free to point me to a duplicate etc if there is one.

Edit: Thanks to Lex for pointing out I was missing a closing tag for the select element, resolving that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `</select>` tag.